# Вывод текста из input в div алерт

Tags: jquery, функции

```
function(a) { 
    var clink = $("#ID22").val();
    if ($(".finder:first", a).attr('href') == undefined) { 
        $('#submit').click();
    } else { 
        $('#error2').fadeIn(1000);$('#error2').text('Ссылка +clink+ уже есть в нашей базе');setTimeout('$("#error2").fadeOut(1000);',3000);
        return false;
    } 
});}
```

Здравствуйте!

Я только начинаю изучать javascript. Так что не осуждайте строго. У меня есть функция которая ищет схожие ссылки на страницах. Но всё это особо не важно.

Проблема в том, что я не могу сделать вывод ссылки (из поля) в "алерт" на дивах. То есть я прописываю

```
var clink = $("#ID22").val();
```

и вставляю

```
$('#error2').text('Ссылка +clink+ уже есть в нашей базе');
```

Но +clink+ не работает. Подправьте пожалуйста, кто знает. :) Буду очень вам благодарен.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Конкатенация строк в джаваскрипте осуществляется так:

```
$('#error2').text('Ссылка ' + clink + ' уже есть в нашей базе');
```

Comment: Ой, огромное Вам спасибо. :)